# Price input pattern html5

Tags: regex, html, grails

I've got input field and I want to check dot existence for value of price input field. The value will be look like this `12.00`. Here is my code

```
<g:textField class="span3" id="price" name="price" required="" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"/>
```

I write something like this `\d+(\.\d{2})?`, but received error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: unexpected char: '\' @ line 135, column 471. \d{2})?"', 745, it) { return "\d+(\.\d{2 ^ 1 error

Comment: I tried it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVXN3/) and it worked find on Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: same for firefox - works fine, check page source, maybe it was encoded by `grails` before output?

Comment: For firefox don't work fine. At least for me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

---

```html
<form>
  <input type='number' pattern='[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?' />
  <button type='submit'>Check</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "11.11.11", will accept. i think it's not a valid price

Answer (score 4):

The right answer is: [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern.

```
pattern="[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. I'd suggest to explain your answer

Comment: When answering a seven year old question with other existing answers the burden is on you to clearly communicate what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always benefit from the addition of some explanation, and regex answers need it even more.

Answer (score 0):

**@Shree,**

The pattern is as follows.
1. [0-9] = allow any number/numeric in a range of 0 to 9
2. *[.]?[0 -9] = if a period is included, only a range number of 0 to 9 allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for dot as decimal separator:

```
pattern="^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}$"
```

Pattern for comma as decimal separator:

```
pattern="^[0-9]+,?[0-9]{0,2}$"
```

This will accept any number with up to two decimal places.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your regex allows a decimal operator without numbers behind! E.g. `012.`. So I would use`^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`.